# Dictionary to return a character list with their indices

Tags: c#

I've been tasked with taking a string and returning a dictionary that has a map of characters to a list of their indices in a given string. The output should show which characters occur where in the given string.

Comment: Can you include the tests? That should give a clear indication of what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: @ScottHannen Added.

Comment: I realize that by answering I'm likely completing some homework assignment. But a) the question shows work, b) it has a unit test, and c) I think seeing a completed solution with comments can help someone learn provided that they actually read through it and understand it.

Comment: @ScottHannen Thank you. I am the type of person that likes to review what I'm being shown and make sure I actually understand what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code passes the test:

```cs
public class CharacterIndexDictionary
{
    public static Dictionary<string, List<int>> ConcordanceForString(string input)
    {
        var result = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();

        for (var index = 0; index < input.Length; index++)
        {
            // Get the character positioned at the current index.
            // We could just use input[index] everywhere, but
            // this is a little easier to read.
            string currentCharacter = input[index].ToString();

            // If the dictionary doesn't already have an entry
            // for the current character, add one.
            if (!result.ContainsKey(currentCharacter))
            {
                result.Add(currentCharacter, new List<int>());
            }

            // Add the current index to the list for
            // the current character.
            result[currentCharacter].Add(index);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

If I wanted to index characters I'd use a `Dictionary<char, List<int>>` instead of using a `string` as the key, but this uses `string` because the test requires it.

Answer (score 0):

This code block is like your code and in a way that you can understand

```
public Dictionary<string, List<int>> ConcordanceForString(string s)
    {
        Dictionary<string, List<int>> newDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();

        List<char> charList = new List<char>();

        foreach (var item in s)
        {
            if (!charList.Any(x => x == item))
            {
                charList.Add(item);

                List<int> itemInds = new List<int>();
                
                for (int i = 0; i< s.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (s[i] == item)
                    {
                        itemInds.Add(i);
                    }
                }

                newDictionary.Add(item.ToString(), itemInds);
            }
        }

      
        return newDictionary;
    }
```

Comment: If you do it like this you're iterating over the entire list for each character in the list. Not that performance is everything, but if the string is 8000 characters long this will go through all 8000 characters, and for each character it will iterate through all 8000 again.

Comment: You right. I know that. But this code like his\her code.

Comment: @karagoz Thank you as well